# Using a static variable value in Qualifier annotation

Tags: spring, spring-el

Is it possible to pass a static variable defined in a class as argument to @Qualifier annotation? I tried the below format and a few other variations, but nothing worked.

```
@Qualifier("T(com.test.Constants).BEAN_NAME")
```

Spring-el works in @Value annotation. For example, below example is valid:

```
@Value("#{ systemProperties['user.region'] }")
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Try with  `@Qualifier(com.test.Constants.BEAN_NAME)`

Comment: thanks- it worked. I couldn't find this info in the documentation. Can you tell me where you found this info or a document I can read?

Comment: Annotation values are compile-time constants. see http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/technotes/guides/language/annotations.html.

Comment: No, don't use constants! Use a annotation like described here: this: https://stackoverflow.com/q/69263925/13822943